# How to change the current character in "for char in string" Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, string

So given this example:

```
string = "string"
for char in string:
    if char = "a":
        # change current character to some other character
    elif char = "b"
        # change current character to some other character
```

how can I make it so that the current character of the string is replaced with some other string
("replace()" changes all of the character of the same type

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i didn't know that string are immutable but i found a workaround for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60808387/8069500) passing trough a list:

```
string = 'aa String aa'
string = list(string)
for index in range(len(string)):
    if string[index] == 'a':
        string[index] = 'c'
string = "".join(string)
```

maybe other method are faster but if you need to specifically loop though the string this would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `replace` or a regex, you can use this code:

```
string = "abstring"
new_chars = []
for char in string:
    if char == "a":
        char = "b"
    elif char == "b":
        char = "c"
    new_chars.append(char)

new_string = "".join(new_chars)
print(string, new_string)
```

Or you could actually use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) which has a `count` option:

```
string = "abstringab"
new_string = string.replace("a", "o", 1)
new_string = new_string.replace("b", "x", 1)
print(new_string)
```